Error: getCredentialAsync no provider dependencies found
I am trying to build signin with google button in android studio and after running the code and downloading all the dependencies after following the video in this documentation and referring the steps in this android's documentation I get the error (as shown in screen shot) .
As i am testing it on Emulator i also get warning:
"Google Play services out of date for com.example.dhm20.  Requires 230815045 but found 201817022"
Could the error be because of this? (I tried updating the play services dependencies and is currently on the latest)
Code:

@Composable
fun SignInScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text("Sign in to your account")

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        val context = LocalContext.current

        val onClick: () -> Unit = {
            val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context)

            val rawNonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            val bytes = rawNonce.toByteArray()
            val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
            val digest = md.digest(bytes)
            val hashedNonce = digest.fold("") { str, it -> str + "%02x".format(it) }

            val googleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
                .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                .setServerClientId(ClientID)
                .setNonce(hashedNonce)
                .build()

            val request = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
                .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
                .build()

            coroutineScope.launch {
                try {
                    val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                        request = request,
                        context = context,
                    )
                    val credential = result.credential

                    val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential
                        .createFrom(credential.data)

                    val googleIdToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken

                    Log.i(TAG, googleIdToken)

                    // Sign in with Firebase using the ID token
                    signInWithGoogle(googleIdToken)

                    Toast.makeText(context, "You are signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    // Navigate to your DHM main screen
                    navController.navigate("DHM_MAIN_SCREEN")

                } catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }

        // Google Sign-In Button
        Button(onClick = onClick) {
            Text("Sign in with Google")
        }
    }
}

suspend fun signInWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
    val firebaseCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
    Firebase.auth.signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential).await()
}

Installed dependencies:
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.4.0"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore")
implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.34.0")
implementation ("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2")
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")



//Authentication with Credential Manager
implementation("androidx.credentials:credentials:1.3.0")
implementation("androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:1.3.0")
implementation ("com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid:googleid:1.1.1")
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.2.0")

implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0")
implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0")

I tried debugging it by setting and deleting the Google OAuth provider in Firebase and the Api console, but I can't seem to get rid of the error.

Another thing I noted, You should place the authentication logic Outside your compose function, store it as a class or an object, then parse it as a parameter. When the Compose function is called again during recomposition, the auth variables do not get reinitialized.

I recently encountered the same problem on my end, this is how I approached it by:

Ensure updated Google Play Services is available in your device (physical/emulator). You can update your device Google Play Services using: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en
In your AndroidManifest.xml, ensure you have the following permissions: INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, and any other specific permission required for the Google services you're using.
Ensure your API keys are well set, also make sure the app id is well set.
Clean and Rebuild your project.
Test on a different device or emulator.


At times, the error messages might be misleading...
Please ensure following

Confirm that you have initialized Firebase in your main.dart file and also ensure that you have added proper google-services.json to your project

Make sure you have enabled providers in firebase console.

Clear and rebuild the project


